# HTML tag inside javascript eval() function

Tags: javascript, html, regex, str-replace

Why in the first case, html em tags are printed normally whereas in the second test, they disappear.

```
var text = "text";
eval("var text = text.replace(/(.*)(ex)(.*)/gi,'$1<em>$2</em>$3');");
console.log(text)   //text -> t<em>ex</em>t
```

but

```
var textx = text.replace("/(.*)(ex)(.*)/gi",'$1<em>$2</em>$3');
console.log(textx) //textx -> text
```

I've looked at the documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval  but can't find an explanation.

Thanks

Comment: Note that the `console.log` in your second code tries to print out a different variable, instead of `textx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first uses a regex to match text and the second uses a string.

There is no `"/(.*)(ex)(.*)/gi"` inside `"text"`. There is `/(.*)(ex)(.*)/gi`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = "text";
var textx = text.replace(/(.*)(ex)(.*)/gi,'$1<em>$2</em>$3'); 
console.log(textx) //textx -> text
```

the problems was that you used a string in the regular expression.
`"/(.*)(ex)(.*)/gi"` -> `/(.*)(ex)(.*)/gi`

and you had a spelling mistake in the `console.log(testx)` -> `console.log(textx)`